# $h \in O(h^2)$ as $h \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

My question is :
$h \in O(h^2)$ as $h \rightarrow 0$ ?

I am only used to use this notation for sequences when $n \rightarrow \infty$. In this case I know that $n \in O(n^2)$.

Can someone confirm it?

Comment: hint: look at $\frac{1}{h}$ and $\frac{1}{h^2}$ then apply the usual reasoning

Comment: The following link might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition

Comment: This looks wrong, or confusingly expressed at best. If $h$ is small then there is not a fixed $C$ for which $h < Ch^2$.

Comment: Use the limit definition, $g\in\mathcal O(f)$ at $a\iff \limsup_{h\to a}\frac{g(h)}{f(h)}...?$

Comment: $h^2$ is much smaller than $h$ for small $h,$ so No!

Comment: I notice my error now, $h$ is not in $O(h^2)$, because $h > ch^2, h \rightarrow 0$. Dahh, my bad can't delete the question now :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it is easier to look at the limit definition of big-$\mathcal O$:

$g\in\mathcal O(f)$ at $a\iff \limsup_{h\to a}\left|\frac{g(h)}{f(h)}\right|<\infty$

You can think on big-$\mathcal O$ like: If you get close to $a$, does $f$ grow faster than $g$?

You can see that forall $|h|<1$ there is $h^2<h$, moreover when $h\to0$ there is $h^2\ll h$, hence $h\notin\mathcal O(h^2)$.

In the limit definition it is immediate:$$\limsup_{h\to0}\left|\frac{h}{h^2}\right|=\lim_{h\to0}\left|\frac{h}{h^2}\right|=\lim_{h\to0}\left|\frac{1}{h}\right|=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{|h|}=\infty\require{cancel}\cancel<\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

In a situation like this, I recommend plugging in some numbers. Here's a table of values:
$$
\begin{array}{c|lll}
h & .1 & .01 & .001 & .0001 & .00001 & .000001 & .0000001 \\
\hline
h^2 & .01 & .0001 & .000001 & .00000001 &.0000000001 & .000000000001 & .00000000000001
\end{array}
$$
So, do you still believe that $h < ch^2$ for some $c$ as $h \to 0$?

Comment: Your last question is incorrect. Be more careful with your quantifiers; it should be "do you still believe that $h < ch^2$ as $h \to 0$, for some $c$?".

Comment: @user21820 If you want to know what I meant by that sentence, look back at the edit history to see the original language of this post. The OP altered the post after I wrote this answer, so apparently my last question had an effect.

Comment: The original question had "and" not "as", so your answer does **not** address it. Also, to be frank I think your post is misleading if not outright wrong. The answer to your question exactly as stated is "yes", but it is the **wrong** definition. The answer to the correct version that I stated is "no".

Comment: I will admit that it takes some imagination to interpret the poor mathematical grammar of the original post. Nonetheless, my post gives numerical evidence for the exact same thing that is proved in the very fine answer of @Holo: there *does not exist* a $c>0$ and a neighborhood of $0$ such that the inequality $h < c h^2$ is true for all $h$ in that neighborhood. I'm not sure what other point you are trying to make.

Comment: What is wrong is that your **order** of quantifiers is wrong, under the natural reading. That is why I clearly stated the correct order in my first comment; "for some c" is the **outermost** quantifier. The truth-value of the claim is opposite with the wrong quantifier order.

Comment: Yeah, I always tell my students to use prenex normal form: put quantifiers first, to avoid these kinds of mathematical ambiguity. I just wish the OP had done so. I'll just leave my post as is for folks to read along with our comment thread.

Comment: Ah okay, sure! I always cringe when deciding whether to write the quantifiers at the front to fit mathematical style, or at the back to fit English style. In the latter case I usually use commas like I did above to ensure there is no ambiguity. =)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Simply note that

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \left|\frac h {h^2}\right|=\lim_{h\to 0} \left|\frac 1 {h}\right|=\infty$$

Comment: Am I missing something obvious? i.e. your answer says "No: we do not have $h \in O(h^2)$", right?

Comment: @T_M that means that $|h^2|$ is arbitrarly smaller than $|h|$ for $h\to 0$.

Comment: @T_M You are correct, that is what this answer says, as does the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's apply a change of variables where $g=\frac{1}{h}$. Note that as $h\to 0$ then $g \to \infty$.

Your question asks whether $\frac{1}{g} = \frac{1}{g^2}$ as $g \to \infty$

Clearly, as $g \to \infty$, 
$$\frac{1}{g} \not \in O(\frac{1}{g^2})$$ Since

$$\lim_{g \to \infty} \left | \frac{\frac{1}{g}}{\frac{1}{g^2}} \right | = \lim_{g \to \infty} \left | g \right| \to \infty$$

Therefore, for all $g>g_0 >0$, $\not \exists M > 0$ such that

$$\left | \frac{1}{g} \right | < M \cdot \left | \frac{1}{g^2} \right |$$

Which is equivalent to for all $0<h < h_0$ $\not \exists M > 0$ such that
$$\left | h \right | < M \cdot \left | h^2 \right |$$

Note: Other answers are more direct, this is a roundabout way to get to the same result.

Comment: You should add $|\cdot |$ everywhere, afterall $1/h\to\pm\infty\ne\infty$